# Ember Resource URL: how to make it use other values rather than ID?

Tags: ember.js

I need to make a Ember Resource to send its query using one of values in its schema.

Let's say I've defined this resource:

```
App.SomeModule = Ember.Resource.define(
{
    url: './api/some',
    schema:
    {
        id: Number,
        fodder: Number,
        whatever: Number,
        units:
        {
            type: Ember.ResourceCollection,
            itemType: 'App.OtherModule',
            url: './api/other/%@'
        }
    }
});
```

When this resource need to load its 'units', it will automatically send a query using the url "api/other/(id). However I need to make it use other value such as (fodder) or (whatever), not id. I think (%@) need to be replaced but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to define `url` as a function instead:

```
units: {
  url: function() {
    // your custom code here:
    return '/api/other/%@'.fmt(this.get('fodder'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to find a way by using your answer as a clue. That `this` in url function indicates `units`, not schema or class itself, so `this.get('fodder')` returns nothing. However further attempts revealed that the function accepts a parameter, which is perhaps given by default. The parameter is the item itself, App.OtherModule in this case. By replacing `this` with this parameter, you can access the class itself.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help (albeit, in a roundabout way) ;)

Comment: Could you post the solution you found? Thanks!

Comment: The solution is simple: just attach and use a parameter when you call the function like this: `url: function(item){ ... item.get('fodder') ...`. By the way, that `App.OtherModule` in my comment should be replaced with `App.SomeModule`(I could not find the edit button).